# Redirect Video Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, rtmp

Let's say that I'm sending RTMP Video with OBS to my C# app e.g `http://my_site/.com`

I'd want to redirect it e.g in Middleware to e.g internal rtmp server - under url `rtmp://internal/live`

How can I perform that "redirect" without destroying video stream?

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ApiKey", out var key))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return;
    }

    if (!apiKeys.Contains(key))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return;
    }

    Redirect(await next.Invoke());
});
```

Do I need to add some support rtmp protocol if I want to just redirect all data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTMP is a bidirectional protocol. You can use a TCP proxy (like ssh tunnel, or ha proxy) in between. But you still need the RTMP server running some ware. That could be in your app, or even just nginx.

If your just trying to “redirect” to another RTMP server you don’t control, any TCP proxy will do. It wouldn’t need to be RTMP aware.

Comment: Generally I "just" want to be **aware** that someone is streaming to my rtmp. I'd want to have some meta data e.g at least under what url e.g `rtmp://internal/live/1234` or to be able to deny that person